# java rabbitmq with Executor thread, created threads keeps running. how to make sure threads are killed?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, executorservice, spring-rabbit

I'm using rabbitmq receiver. it gets multiple requests at the same time so I'm creating threads to handle multiple requests concurrently.

problem is either I create  newSingleThreadExecutor or newFixedThreadPool they remain running 
executor.shutdown(); or executor.shutdownNow(); will not close threads below is sample

```
 public void receiver(String message) {

         ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
                :
            executor.execute(c);
                :
            executor.shutdown();
            try {
                executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                executor.shutdownNow();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
        }
```

below is my rabbitmq config

```
 @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                             MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(receiver recv) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(recv, "receiver");
    }
```

and threads remain in like 
 **Thread[pool-1-thread-"number"]**

threads are created as many requests i get in the receiver and never shuts down.

how to avoid this condition or is it best to remove the multi-thread concept entirely ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an executor within your listener in the first place or you will risk message loss.

Increase the container `concurrentConsumers` and the framework will manage concurrency for you.

Comment: i other words what i'm trying to archive can be done without the executor and by increase of concurrentConsumers, thank you